# Sending email with google app engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, email

Im tring to send a simple email with this code using google app engine.
 But nothing happens, is there something i have to configure in order to use the mail api?
 This runs on localhost.
 I am using gmail as mail host.

```
   String host = "smtp.google.com";
String to = "example@yahoo.fr";
String from = "example@gmail.com";
String subject = "this is a test";
String messageText = "test";
boolean sessionDebug = false;
// Create some properties and get the default Session.
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.host", host);
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);

// Set debug on the Session
// Passing false will not echo debug info, and passing True will.

mailSession.setDebug(sessionDebug);

// Instantiate a new MimeMessage and fill it with the 
// required information.

Message msg = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
InternetAddress[] address = { new InternetAddress(to) };
msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, address);
msg.setSubject(subject);
msg.setSentDate(new Date());
msg.setText(messageText);

// Hand the message to the default transport service
// for delivery.

Transport.send(msg);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When running the AppEngine development server locally, anything sent via the Mail service will not actually be sent - it will just be logged to the console

See [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/overview#Development_Server)

> When an application running in the development server calls the Mail service to send an email message, the message is printed to the log. The Java development server does not send the email message.

In addition, the `from` address must be (from [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail#Senders_and_Recipients))

- The email of an app administrator
- The email of the currently logged in user who signed in using a Google Account
- A valid email receiving address from the app

Comment: So is there no way to send an email from a GAE project? Or just not using this way?

Comment: You can, just only from specific addresses and the local development server just logs emails to the console

Comment: I was checking everything but seemed right and mail was not sent. Haha! You saved my time.

Answer (score 1):

The sender should be your own Gmail email address instead of `example@gmail.com`

Reason is because the SMTP server needs to authenticate you.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, GAE doesn't allow the use of the admin accounts any more. you need to use the service account: `project-id@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`

My previous projects still work with admin accounts, but the recently created projects just don't allow me to use any of the admin accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Other than email not working on localhost or due to the sender email not being the authenticated one, I have experienced that email does not work even when the version is not the default one. I could not find this documented anywhere.

For example:
`nondefaultversion-dot-myapp.appspot.com` (email does not work, no error logs)
`myapp.appspot.com` (email works)

Please confirm if others have also faced this issue.